# Correct way to retrieve text from a text-entity in A-frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I was experimenting with retrieving text from text components but surprisingly I couldn't get the desired result using the method that was in the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#components).

Resorting to getAttribute("text") is enough for my needs but I'm looking to understand why the method described in "textdemo2" doesn't work.

```
      <a-entity mixin="marker" position="-1 2 0.01" ></a-entity>
      <a-entity position="-1 2 0"
                text="width: 2; lineHeight: 50; letterSpacing: 5; color: white;
                value: [LINE AND LETTER SPACING] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam">
      </a-entity>

      <a-text id="textdemo2"
              position="-1 3 0"
              width="2"
              letter-spacing="5"
              line-height="50"
              value="Hello, World!" ></a-text>
      
      <script>
        const textdemo = document.querySelector('#textdemo').getAttribute("text");
        console.log(textdemo)

        const textdemo2 = document.querySelector('#textdemo2').component.texts.value;
        console.log(textdemo2)
      </script>
```

Side Question: I'm also confused as to which text entity creation method is best to use,  is straight forward enough but is there any reason to ever use the a-entity version?

Comment: It looks like a typo, you wrote .component.texts instead of .components.text but I didn't test so it's maybe something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a-text ...></a-text>` and [other primitives](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/primitives/a-text.html#sidebar) are just short-hands for an `<a-entity>` + [components](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html#sidebar). My personal preference is using `<a-entity>` since it gives more clarity on what's going on. To [get the value of component properties](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#getattribute-componentname) use getAttribute:

```
  const textdemo2 = document.querySelector('#textdemo2').getAttribute("text").value;
```